# How to set up a Spring MVC project using maven?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple spring mvc project using maven but in this list (IN PICTURE) I am not able to find the artifactId for the spring mvc project. What i am missing here? [image]

Answer (score 0):

This usually just means that your index doesn't already have the archetype you want; you might need to add a catalog.

Instead, though, I recommend [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), a tool that lets you select the components you want and builds a ready-to-go POM for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add Remote Archetype in your eclipse it will show you that option. Following are the steps:

File--->New---> Maven Project---->Next--->Click on tab Configure

Separate window will open... Maven-->Archetypes-->Click on Add Remote Catalog--> In Catalog File type "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml" and click on Apply and then Ok

Now in new Maven Project select Remote Archetype from Catalog and you will find webapp-j2ee14 option there.